# What is the best way to mangle layer2 packets in linux?

Tags: linux

I have multiple ethernet interfaces and I want to send some packets through eth1 regardless of packet headers. I can set destination mac address as I want to do layer 2 communication.

Looks like Netfilter is not a good method for this as mac addresses are filled after post-routing hooks.

Is there something like netfilter for layer2 mangling in linux?

Comment: Are you asking for a software package or way to write your own software to accomplish this?

Comment: I have my kernel module which does L3 mangling using Netfilter hooks. Now, I'm thinking of achieving L2 mangling, but it is not clear for me as I don't want to directly call xmit() functions.